# Magento Rerouting Controller, What am I missing?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to override a controller for magenta, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. In my modules config.xml file I have the following

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <modules>
                        <Mymodule_Sales before="Mage_Customer_Account">Mymodule_Sales_Account</Mymodule_Sales>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

So my question is, what else am I missing ? Is this all I have to do to override a controller ? My module is being picked up by magento because I was already able to override a block. Just having issues with this.

Comment: you don't have to write that `<use>` tag.

Comment: also, I think `Mage_Customer_Account` should be `Mage_Customer` only.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I was doing wrong was stating the before="" path incorrectly

instead of having

```
Mage_Customer_Account
```

It needed to be...

```
Mage_Customer
```

I guess you have to tell magento which module to override and magento will figure out which controller and action your trying to override just by you simply creating the file and action.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you enable your module in /app/etc/modules/Company_Modulename.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Modulename>
            <version>0.9.8</version>
        </Company_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <modulename>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Company_Modulename before="Mage_Customer">Company_Modulename</Company_Modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </modulename>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <modulename>
                    <file>company_modulename.xml</file>
                </modulename>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit your php and xml aswell? See [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) for a useful reference with all the steps to overriding a controller

Comment: Yes I did but i figured the issue.